# Convert hex color code to color name

Tags: r, colors

How can I translate a hex representation of a color to its corresponding name?

For example, consider the following colors:

```
rainbow(4)
# "#FF0000FF" "#80FF00FF" "#00FFFFFF" "#8000FFFF"
```

What are their names (hoping a name exist for each code)?

I discovered the function `col2rgb()` but it does not exaclty what I am needing.

Comment: Scrap an hex color data.frame and then fetch in this look up table for the color name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may use the convenience function `color.id` from the `plotrix` package*:

> Given a color specified as a hex string, find the closest match in the table of known (named) colors.

```
library(plotrix)
sapply(rainbow(4), color.id)
# $`#FF0000FF`
# [1] "red"  "red1"
# 
# $`#80FF00FF`
# [1] "chartreuse"  "chartreuse1"
# 
# $`#00FFFFFF`
# [1] "cyan"  "cyan1"
# 
# $`#8000FFFF`
# [1] "purple"
```

---

*Credits to Jim Lemon and his answer here: [Convert color hex code to color names](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2015-April/427663.html).

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps not the most elegant solution, but it should get the job done:

```
color.names <- function(d) {
  # get RGB components of d and convert to data frame
  z2 <- as.data.frame(t(col2rgb(d)))

  # get RGB components of standard colors and convert them to data frame
  z <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(colors(distinct=T),col2rgb)))
  colnames(z) <- colnames(z2)
  z$name <- rownames(z)

  # EDIT: original answer used 'merge', which messed up the order
  library(dplyr)
  z2 %>% left_join(z) %>% select(name) 

}

color.names(rainbow(4))
#   name
# 1  red
# 2 <NA>
# 3 cyan
# 4 <NA>
```

The function `color.names` uses the same input as `col2rgb`, i.e.

> vector of any of the three kinds of R color specifications, i.e.,
>   either a color name (as listed by colors()), a hexadecimal string of
>   the form "#rrggbb" or "#rrggbbaa" (see rgb), or a positive integer i
>   meaning palette()[i].

so you can use it to get the names of standard colors by doing `color.names(1:8)`

For computational efficiency, data set with standard colors can be precalculated as in this example:

```
init.color.names <- function() {
  z <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(colors(distinct=T),col2rgb)))
  colnames(z) <- colnames(z2)
  z$name <- rownames(z)
  library(dplyr)

  function(d) {
    z2 <- as.data.frame(t(col2rgb(d)))     
    z2 %>% left_join(z) %>% select(name)   }
}
cl <- init.color.names()
cl(1:3)
cl(rainbow(4))
```

Comment: Looks good. Thank you. The "NA" means that no name exist for this specific code? I guess that through a loop, one may seek for closely related colors that have a name.

Comment: Yes, "NA' means no matching color. It is an interesting idea about the closely related colors, but I am not really sure how to properly define the distance between colors.

Comment: you'll just want to get the three values and calculate the euclidean distance

Answer (score 4):

Probably better ways but here's one using indexing:

```
colors()[match(rgb(t(col2rgb(rainbow(4))), 
    maxColorValue = 255), c(rgb(t(col2rgb(colors())), maxColorValue = 255)))]


## [1] "red"  NA     "cyan" NA
```

Comment: what package is 'col2hex' from?

Comment: `colors()[match(rainbow(4), paste0(col2hex(colors()),'FF'))]` as an alternative to your answer

Comment: @MaratTalipov my own `reports` package.  I didn't mean to include it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more "tidy approach to the problem. This creates a lookup table for the RGB hex code and color name (from `colors()`).

```
library(tidyverse)

color_lookup <- colors(distinct = TRUE) |> 
  enframe() |> 
  rename(color_name = value) |> 
  select(color_name) |> 
  mutate(rgb = map(color_name, col2rgb),
         red = map_int(rgb, 1),
         green = map_int(rgb, 2),
         blue = map_int(rgb, 3),
         rgb_hex = pmap_chr(list(red, green, blue), .f = ~rgb(..1, ..2, ..3, maxColorValue = 255)))

# A tibble: 502 x 6
   color_name    rgb             red green  blue rgb_hex
   <chr>         <list>        <int> <int> <int> <chr>  
 1 white         <int [3 x 1]>   255   255   255 #FFFFFF
 2 aliceblue     <int [3 x 1]>   240   248   255 #F0F8FF
 3 antiquewhite  <int [3 x 1]>   250   235   215 #FAEBD7
 4 antiquewhite1 <int [3 x 1]>   255   239   219 #FFEFDB
 5 antiquewhite2 <int [3 x 1]>   238   223   204 #EEDFCC
 6 antiquewhite3 <int [3 x 1]>   205   192   176 #CDC0B0
 7 antiquewhite4 <int [3 x 1]>   139   131   120 #8B8378
 8 aquamarine    <int [3 x 1]>   127   255   212 #7FFFD4
 9 aquamarine2   <int [3 x 1]>   118   238   198 #76EEC6
10 aquamarine3   <int [3 x 1]>   102   205   170 #66CDAA
# ... with 492 more rows
```

Then you can do a left_join with your RGB hex code to get the associated color name (if it exists in `colors()`)