# How to map selected hex codes to color names

Tags: r, colors, palette, color-palette

I would like to select distinct colors for the levels available in a factored column.

```
levels(iris$Species)
# [1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"
```

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33144808/4836511), I found that selecting distinct colors using the `brewer.pal` function is optimal and/or easy. I have identified the solution as

```
data.frame(values=levels(iris$Species),
           colhex=brewer.pal(3,'Accent'))

#       values  colhex
# 1     setosa #7FC97F
# 2 versicolor #BEAED4
# 3  virginica #FDC086
```

However, I would like to map these hex codes to color names as (expected output):

```
#       values  colhex colnames
# 1     setosa #7FC97F color1
# 2 versicolor #BEAED4 color2
# 3  virginica #FDC086 color3
```

How to achieve this mapping?

Alternatively, is there any package which provides the color names with hex codes for `n` (say `n=85+`) distinct values.

There is another way to identify the colors present, using:

```
r_colors <- cbind(colors(), t(col2rgb(colors())))
```

I feel this approach is difficult to identify the `n` distinct possible colors.

Comment: @Henrik After doing my homework, I have posted this question to find a better possible solution. The `color.names(rainbow(4))` in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28461584/4836511) gives only 2 out of 4 color names. As getting nearly 100% color names is highly important, I have requested for any possible elegant solutions.

Comment: For the best possible solution arrived in the discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45090183/4836511